# How to know if a page belongs to a Facebook Business using Facebook Graph API/Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

Using the Facebook Graph API, i want to know if a page (with a #page_id) belongs to a Facebook Business (with #business_id)

The only solution i've found is to request API :

```
GET #business_id/client_pages 
GET #business_id/owned_pages
```

I've to use pagination (which can lead to lots of requests before finding the page in the list)

Is there a direct solution like `GET #business_id/client_pages?page_id=#page_id` ?

Comment: Simply go the other way around …? The `page` object has a `business` field.

Comment: @CBroe Querying field=business only returns the business associated to the page if you're admin of the page. If you're not admin or if your Business is only "client" and not "owner" of the page, it returns nothing

Comment: @CBroe There is also a field=agencies doing the job if you've got a page token. But the admin user of the Facebook Business has no right on the page at the query time, so it's not possible to have a page token to query "agencies" field

Comment: Well then you’ll likely have to use pagination; the documentation for the Business Manager API doesn’t manage any filtering possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, a workaround is to create an Admin System User:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/systemuser/

Then try to assign the user to the page (without the "role" parameter) :

```
POST #page_id/assigned_users?business=#business_id&user=#business_scoped_user_id
```

The page doesn't belong to the Business Manager if you got this error :

> (#10) You do not have permission to perform this action. This action
>   requires that you can MANAGE_PERMISSIONS on a managing business
>   account.  Or it requires that you can ADMINISTER on this object Note:
>   to use do this action on behalf of a business account the "business"
>   field must be set.

The page belongs to the Business Manager if you got this error :

> "(#100) Requires exactly one and only one of the params: role,tasks",